# How to convert a vector of integers into a matrix of binary representation with NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np
I = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 15, 16, 32, 64, 128])
```

I would like to convert each item in the array into its binary representation.

**Desired output:**

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Whats the most straight forward way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can accomplish this.

**One way to do it:**

```
# Your array
I = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 15, 16, 32, 64, 128])

B = ((I.reshape(-1,1) & (2**np.arange(8))) != 0).astype(int)
print(B[:,::-1])
```

**You can also do this:**

```
I = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 15, 16, 32, 64, 128], dtype=np.uint8)
print(np.unpackbits(I[:, np.newaxis], axis=1))
```

I personalty would recommend the first method!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use bin() function to convert an integer to a binary string.

One of the possible solution can be:

```
[list(bin(num)[2:].zfill(8)) for num in I ]
```

Here I am using list comprehension for iterating over the array and then for each number in the array, I am applying bin function to convert it to the binary string. Then I am using zfill(8) to add zeros at the beginning of the string to make it of length 8, as required by your output format. Then it is typecasted into a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.array([[int(d) for d in '{0:08b}'.format(el)] for el in I])
```

This should give you the desired output, {0:08b} gives you the binary representation of your number consisting of 8 digits as a string, in a second list comprehension the binary number is split into digits and then result is converted to a numpy array.